# Turning Django web app to a Desktop app

Tags: django

I am very comfortable with Django, and I was wondering about whether there is some way to convert a Django web app into a Desktop app (may be not 100%), so that I can distribute it to users, instead of learning a GUI framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but if you really, really don't want to learn a GUI framework, in your place I'd consider packaging your Django web application with a small web server in the distributable package, with the Django app configured to run on localhost on the web server. Then I'd include a script that launches a browser pointing at the starting page of your Django app as the "executable".

If not configured properly this could be considered weak from a security point of view.

Comment: "packaging your Django web application with a small web server in the distributable package, with the Django app configured to run on localhost on the web server"
Any links/guidance/etc.. on how to do such wrapping ?